# Dealing with duplicate hash data in text file - keeping one unique line and deleting duplicates

Tags: text-processing, hashsum, duplicate

Thanks to this forum I was able to process a large text file containing filenames and hashes and end up with a list of files with identical hashes as shown below:

```
file_35.txt 8208ad321576b521b23b07b9ba598e5c43b03ec4172c96fdbd35a858ec205ae6
file_87.txt 8208ad321576b521b23b07b9ba598e5c43b03ec4172c96fdbd35a858ec205ae6
file_32.txt aaf6b8c4a95d0e8f191784943ba1ea5c0b4d4baab733efe8ceb8b35478b6afd2
file_58.txt aaf6b8c4a95d0e8f191784943ba1ea5c0b4d4baab733efe8ceb8b35478b6afd2
file_89.txt aaf6b8c4a95d0e8f191784943ba1ea5c0b4d4baab733efe8ceb8b35478b6afd2
```

I want to DELETE lines that contain duplicate hashes so that I will end up with a text file containing unique hashes as below:

```
file_35.txt 8208ad321576b521b23b07b9ba598e5c43b03ec4172c96fdbd35a858ec205ae6
file_32.txt aaf6b8c4a95d0e8f191784943ba1ea5c0b4d4baab733efe8ceb8b35478b6afd2
```

Once this is done I will be able to create scripts to move and delete the files I want to save and those I want to delete.

Comment: Easy to understand is this `awk` one. `awk '!seen[$2]++' filename`

Answer (score 1):

If your file is already sorted, how about:

```
uniq --skip-field=1 file
```

otherwise you can sort your file first and then use `uniq`:

```
sort -k2 file | uniq --skip-field=1
```

Output:

```
file_35.txt 8208ad321576b521b23b07b9ba598e5c43b03ec4172c96fdbd35a858ec205ae6
file_32.txt aaf6b8c4a95d0e8f191784943ba1ea5c0b4d4baab733efe8ceb8b35478b6afd2
```

Comment: I don't think skipping the first 11 characters will work - the filename length varies from short to very long - the above is a simplification. Any suggestions for variable filename length?

Comment: @speld_rwong You are right! I edited my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Just wondering, what defines a field? If it is an empty space this may be a problem. My example may have been too simple - some filenames contain spaces. e.g. hd12_picture of giant trees 005.jpg

Comment: From `man uniq`: `A field is a run of blanks (usually spaces and/or TABs), then non-blank characters.`. If your filenames contain spaces, assuming the hash is the last field you can use a `awk` solution, i.e. `awk '!z[$NF]++' file`. I did a quick test and this should work.